# Find the inverse of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A,B,C,M$ were four matrices such that $M=ABC$, $M$ and $B$ invertible and $A,C$ need not to be square and invertible. What is inverse of $B$?

Comment: Your question says to prove that B is an invertible matrix, but you already mentioned M and B are invertible

Comment: If $A$ and $C$ are not square, there is no way you can recover $B$, because information is lost in the course of forming the product $ABC$. Hence you cannot determine $B^{-1}$ too.

Answer (score 2):

$$M=ABC\implies B=(CM^{-1}A)^{-1}$$

Comment: $C$ and $A$ need not to be invertible

Comment: But you have that $M$ is invertible, so $$M^{-1}=(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$$ so they must be invertible.